# HTML "Set as default" in an app

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

Im currently working with a project that uses Apache Cordova. In our HTML-file, we have a search box, where user can input ie. "CLASS A" and set it as default if he/she wishes so. What is the easiest way to make this happen that when user re-opens the app, the app remembers the input? Since we are only creating an (native) app for android and IOS cookies wont do. Is the local storage easiest and right way to approach this one? How should it be implemented in the code? We have HTML/CSS/JS in our project if that matters.

Providing a snippet from HTML;

```
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div id="search">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <div id="timetable">
                </div>

                <form onsubmit="return false" id="searchform">
                    <input type="text" oninput="upperCaseGroup(this)" id="field" placeholder="Search group's timetable" maxlength="100" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="text" oninput="upperCaseClass(this)" id="fieldClass" placeholder="Search room's timetable" maxlength="100" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
                    <p id="searchNotifi">* Search timetables inputting desired group or room id. (ie. TITE14 / A420.2) <a href style="color: deeppink" id="hidemsg">Okay!</a></p>
                    <label for="remember" id="mlabel"><input type="checkbox" id="remember" data-role="none" />Set as default</label>
                    <!-- <div id="hae" class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Search</div> -->
                    <input type="button" value="Search" id="search" class="btn openpanel" onclick="executeSearch()" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: What code looks like in app]

This is how the code looks like in app (with JS functions and such).

So everything workd correctly, but how can we set search as default, so the app remembers the input next time user opens the app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Local Storage would work, I would think

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage`, it persists even when the browser is closed and reopened and will be something like that.

```
localStorage.setItem("val1","some text");

localStorage.getItem("val1")
//some text
```

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would not rely on using `localStorage` if you want to make sure your data never gets cleared by the system. As mentioned [here](https://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/) `localStorage` will get cleared if your device has low memory available.
I'd suggest using one of the following *persistent* storage possibilities:

- [Native storage](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage)
- [SQLite storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

Though SQLite will be a bit overkill for remembering a users selection, so native storage is probably the way to go.

**Usage (after adding the plugin):**

Storing an item:

```
NativeStorage.setItem("key",<value>, <success-callback>, <error-callback>);
```

Retrieving an item:

```
NativeStorage.getItem("key",<success-callback>, <error-callback>);
```